# How can I search by DateTime in Hibernate query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, spring-data

I am using Spring Data framework, and I have query in my repository that looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Contract c "
        + " WHERE LOWER(c.name) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm) "
        + " OR LOWER(c.legalName) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm) "
        + " OR cast(c.startDate as string) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm)"
        )   
public Page<Contract> findAllBySearchTerm(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Pageable page)
```

I can search contracts by name and legalName, but i have problem to search contracts by **startDate**, which is in format *"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"*.
I tried to cast startDate to varchar, but function **cast()** does not work ok with Oracle (which is my database).

I also tried this, but also does not work:

```
+ " to_char(c.startDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm)"
```

I tried to cast searchTerm to DateTime, and to compare that with startDate, but I could not make that work with function **to_date()** .

Does anybody have some solutions for this problem? Some useful links maybe?

Comment: Shouldn't you use different params for `searchTerm`?

Comment: That is the point. I want to use one searchTerm for searching through varchar columns and also Date columns.

Comment: The query performance will be awful and the maintainability will make cry to any programmer. Why to have such odd design?

Comment: I thought there is a function that will cast date as string in JPA query, or opposite?! And I have the same problem on several tables in my app.

Comment: I agree with @luigi, such a query will result in poor performance, because you are only interested in one of the 3 columns for any given query.

Comment: To add on to @LuiggiMendoza's remark, note also that rdbms (often) do not use indices for multiple predicates combined with `OR`.

Comment: @Django the problem is the extremely poor performance of the query. If you want/need to use a single term, it would be better passing another argument that states which parameter to use. Usually, when you do this, you build the query dynamically and append the parameters dynamically as well.

Answer (score 0):

For this query

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Contract c "
    + " WHERE LOWER(c.name) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm) "
    + " OR LOWER(c.legalName) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm) "
    + " OR cast(c.startDate as string) LIKE LOWER(:searchTerm)"
    )   
public Page<Contract> findAllBySearchTerm(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Pageable page)`
```

- Consider using = instead of LIKE, because there are no wildcards in your query
- For a Date, consider converting the searchTerm string into a Date object instead of the SQL Date Column into a string? so something like `OR c.startDate = :searchTerm` where the searchTerm is a Date object